# java.lang.IllegalStateException:Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory

Tags: maven, jsf, jakarta-ee, weblogic

I am trying to deploy an ear maven project into WebLogic 12c, that contains JSF 2 in its war sub module.

After working with it for several days, I got a message and I am not able to resolve it.

> [HTTP:101216]Servlet: "Faces Servlet" failed to preload on startup in
>   Web application: "/". java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find
>   backup for factory javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory.

My related dependencies in POM :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Don't you need to assign `javaee-web-api` the `provided` scope?

Comment: @Tiny : I have tried your suggestion and so many others ! but finally I finally find out that weblogic 12.1.1 is not compatible with jsf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working on this problem for about 20 days(!) finally I found out that Weblogic 12.1.1 has a bug on working with JSF. I upgraded my weblogic to 12.1.2 and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed this problem on our Weblogic server (Version: 12.1.3.0.0) after first undeploying a JSF application and deploying another JSF application.

I got everything running again by removing all my jsf applications, restarting the entire application server (not only the nodes) and redeploying the jsf application.